# How can I access the console-output of a nwjs-applications?

Tags: javascript, debugging, nwjs

I am trying to play with nwjs and I can not figure out how to debug.

I have basic script by tutorial:

```
require('nw.gui').Window.get().showDevTools()
var menu = new nw.Menu();

menu.append(new nw.MenuItem({
  label: 'Item A',
  click: function(){
    alert('You have clicked at "Item A"');
  }
}));

menu.append(new nw.MenuItem({ label: 'Item B' }));
menu.append(new nw.MenuItem({ type: 'separator' }));
menu.append(new nw.MenuItem({ label: 'Item C' }));

document.body.addEventListener('contextmenu', function(ev) {
  console.log("Hello");

  ev.preventDefault();
  menu.popup(ev.x, ev.y);

  return false;
}, false);
```

I added two lines of code:

```
require('nw.gui').Window.get().showDevTools();
console.log("Hello");
```

I run a script and see two windows:

[image]

if I right click on the text so that the displayed menu, but not `console.log("Hello")` output in debug toolbar.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: is this specific to windows 10, or rather [tag:nwjs]?

Answer (score 1):

For showDevTools() to work, you need to download the SDK version of nwjs. You are getting a white screen because it is the normal version. With the SDK version, the showDevTools() will open the chrome Developer Tools, which includes a tab for the console output. See the image below:
[image: Developer Tools Console]